# How to practice problems from textbooks that don't have a solution manual

Tags: reference-request, self-learning

I'm looking to do a bunch of problems from one of my textbooks to become more comfortable with a topic, but I have a problem: the textbook doesn't have solutions, and there isn't a solution manual. How am I supposed to know whether I'm doing things right/how do learn more techniques (or better techniques) to solve the problems? In general, how do I gain anything from solving problems from a textbook that doesn't have a solution manual available?

Comment: I, personally, used to only rarely check if the numerical answer of a math problem is correct. More imporant is to **understand** why the problem is solved the way that it is. If the textbook clearly lays out the approaches, you should be all good. Don't worry about the numerical final answer, just do your best and keep in mind that the real goal is to understand the methods.

Comment: Yeah but that's what I'm looking for: approaches and techniques. Textbooks do prove theorems (which provide some insight into techniques that can be helpful), but they're hardly enough to master the problems. I'm talking about more proof-based problems, and textbooks not having manuals highlighting good ways of approaching those.

Comment: I definitely agree with Matti, however, there are some good people on the internet who post their answers (handwritten) online, I found some for my Linear Algebra course [here](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780321982384-linear-algebra-and-its-applications-5th-edition/). You can also look for solution manual in the Library Genesis database (not sure if legal though).

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good thing to get used to having answers at hand when you solve problems. You need to get stuck and you need to work hard to unstick yourself if you want to ever learn something. Having the solutions at hand is a distraction for your mind that will prevent you getting into really deep and 100% involved thought. Bless the author of your book.

Comment: In real life there is no solution manual, either. If you get used to only work on problems which have a solution written down somewhere you'll get stuck in some academic cage. Try to solve the problem and understand the solution, that's what you will have to do when you get a paid job, too.

Comment: FWIW, I think it's a totally legitimate math stackexchange question to say, "I wrote a solution to this question, and I hoping to have someone check it..."  I have gladly answered such questions when I have seen them.  Obviously, don't spam it; use it sparingly.  

A bit of further advice: Wolfram Alpha can check pure calculations for you.  So, for example, if  you think you already "set up the integral correctly" (if you're studying multivariable Calculus, say), you can use that to check the final calculation.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer I could give to you is: it takes time. When you are not very experienced, it is quite difficult to be sure you are doing things right. But there are some tips that could help you out. Most first-year courses involve problems that are strongly connected to calculations. For example, you may have to evaluate limits, derivatives, integrals and so on. For this, you can always check your answers using programs like [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) or MATHEMATICA. If you are dealing with more advanced subjects such as analysis, linear algebra and so on, math.stack is a really good place to discuss your doubts and show your attempts to solve problems. Besides, although your book may not have the answers for its problems, the problems it proposes might be topics of carefuly discussion in another book, so it is very important that you consult more than one reference when studying. Other usefull materials are lecture notes from other professors/universities around the world. In any case, as time goes by you tend to be more experienced and you start to have a "feeling" of what makes sense and what does not. This comes with practice and, lets be honest, also with many mistakes!